# Sets that are closed or open in other sets

Tags: general-topology

I fear this is terribly basic, so basic that I was sure there would be an answer somewhere, but I can't one.  Anyway, am working through do Carmo's differential geometry book.  He talks about closed and open sets.  And I think I get what they are.  But then he starts talking about one set being closed "in" another set, or open "in" another set.  I can't see where such concepts are defined, and I can't find a definition anywhere on the internet.  So, again, I think I understand what "open" and "closed" mean in and of themselves.  But what does it mean that some set is "*closed in*" or "*open in*" some other set?  Perhaps "A open in B" means that A has no boundary other than whatever boundary B may have?  Perhaps "A closed in B" means that if A has a boundary, that boundary is a subset of B?  Or ... heck if I know ...

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subspace_topology

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Being open/closed is not a property of a set. It is a property of some set with respect to another set (or more precisely: to some topological space).

In order for something to be open/closed there has to be some superspace, some universe. Nowadays we defined open/closed via [topology](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topology). Given a topological space $(X,\tau)$, a subset $U\subseteq X$ being open in $(X,\tau)$ simply means that $U\in \tau$. Analogusly $F\subseteq X$ is closed in $(X,\tau)$ if $X\backslash F\in\tau$. So the first observation is that we can change topology on $X$ to $(X,\tau_2)$ so that a subset that was previously open in $(X,\tau)$ is no longer open in $(X,\tau_2)$. This can be done for any open subset, except $\emptyset$ and $X$ itself (which are always open and closed).

Now if $A\subseteq X$ then it is well known that $(A,\tau')$ is a topological space, where $\tau'=\{A\cap U\}_{U\in\tau}$. This is also known as [the subspace topology](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subspace_topology) and it is well defined for any subset $A\subseteq X$.

And so one may ask a question: given $A\subseteq X$, if $V\subseteq A$ is open in $A$ (meaning $V\in\tau'$) then is it also open in $X$ (meaning $V\in\tau$)? Sometimes it is, sometimes it is not. Few examples:

1. $X=\mathbb{R}$ with the Euclidean topology, $A=(0,1)$, then any open subset in $A$ is also open in $X$. But $(0,0.5]$ is closed in $A$, while it is not closed in $X$.
2. More generally: if $A\subseteq X$ is open (resp. closed) in $X$ and $U\subseteq A$ is open (resp. closed) in $A$ then $U$ is open (resp. closed) in $X$.
3. $X=\mathbb{R}$ with the Euclidean topology, $A=[0,1]$. Here for example $(0.1,0.9)$ is open both in $X$ and in $A$. However $[0,0.5)$ is open in $A$, because $[0,0.5)=A\cap (-1,0.5)$, while it is not open in $X$ (the Euclidean topology on $\mathbb{R}$ does not allow half closed intervals).

Comment: I *really* appreciate your help.  But I'm in over my head.  Can any of this be re-phrased for someone who doesn't even know what a "topological space" is?  Thanks, and I really do mean thanks.

Comment: @bob.sacamento well, you need some definition of open/closed. Are you working with metric spaces? What is your background?

Comment: Trying to work through do Carmo.  So this is all various subsets of R^3, especially surfaces.  He says A is "open" if every point in A has a neighborhood that is a subset of A.  And A is "closed" if it contains all of its limit points.

Comment: More generally, I've worked through calculus (including multi-dimensional) and differential equations and linear algebra.  Enough to get through alot of the differential geometry I'm studying.  But I'm pretty much out of my depth now.

Answer (score 0):

Bear with me.

When we talk of a set $A$ being open and/or closed (i.e. topology) we assume there is a "universe" set in which $A$ "lives" and set $A$ is open and/or closed according to the rules of this universe.

A simple example is the "universe" is $\mathbb R$ and $(1,2)$ is open because.... well, it fits all the definitions.

But there are many possible choices for the "universe".  So long as $A \subseteq X$ then we can consider $X$ to be the universe, and we can talk about whether $A$ is open and/or close within the rules of $X$ being or choice of universe.

In our example $(1,2) \subseteq [0, 15) \subseteq \mathbb R$ so we can consider $[0,15)$ as our universe. And $(1,2)$ is open in $[0,15)$ because is still fits all the definitions.

[Note:  For the statement "$A$ is/is not open/closed in $X$" to even make any sense we must have that $A \subseteq X$.]

An issue might come about when we consider $A \subseteq X \subseteq U$. And $A$ might or might not be open/and or closed according to the rules of one universe but not according to the rules of the other universe.

Consider then set $[13,15)\subseteq [0, 15) \subseteq\mathbb R$.

Clearly $[13,15)$ is not closed in $\mathbb R$ because $15$ is an open end point and closed sets can't have open endpoints.

(Okay, the definition is more formal than that.  $15$ is a *limit point* of $[13,15)$ and $15\not \in [13,15)$ and "closed" by definition means contains all its limit points and $[13,15)$ does *not* contain $15$.)

But is $[13,15)$ closed in $[0, 15)$?  You might say "of course not" it still has an open point about $15$".  But.... $15$ does not *exist* in the universe of $[0,15)$.  So it doesn't make any more sense to talk about an open point at $15$ then it does to talk about an open point at $\text{Barbar the elephant}$.

(More formally the limit points of $[13,15)$ are all the values between $13$ and $15$ inclusive.  As all the points between $[13, 15)$ in our univers are $[13, 15)$ they are all in the set.  So $[13,15)$ is closed.)

Also consider $[0, 1)$.  That is not open in $\mathbb R$.  It is not open because $0 \in [0,1)$ and $0$ is *not* an interior point.  It isn't an interior point because if we can't find any $(0-\epsilon, 0+\epsilon)\subset [0, 1)$. That is because $(0-\epsilon,0)$ will always have points that are *not* in $[0,1)$.

But that isn't true if our universe is $[0, 15)$.  If we consider all the $x\in [0, 15$ so that $0 -\frac 12 < x < 0 + \frac 12$ then $0 \le x < \frac 12$.  (We can *not* have $x < 0$ because then $x$ would not be in our universe.)  Ans as all $[0,\frac 12) \subset [0,1)$ that means $0$ *is* an interior point.

(And all the other points in $(0,1)$ are interior points.)

So all the points of $[0,1)$ are interior points (**!!!!IF!!!!!** our universe contains *not* negative numbers) so $[0,1)$ *is* open in $[0,15)$.

.....

That's it in a nutshell.  We can have all sorts of different definition of open/closed depending on which "universe" they live in, but to say a set $A$ is "open in $X$"  means $A \subset X$ and according to the definitions of $X$ as our universe, $A$ is open.

Comment: So, how about, given $A\subseteq B$, A is not closed in B if B contains limit points of A that A itself does not contain.  So if A contains all of its limit points that are also contained in B, A is closed in B.  And ... I'm still trying to find a concise way to say "open".  How am I doing so far?

Comment: Yeah, for the most part.  But we need to get out of the notion that there is some "real" uber-universe somewhere.  It's not that $A$ has some limit points and we check which ones of them are in $B$.  It's that $B$ is the entire universe and nothing outside $B$ exists for our purposes.  So if $A$ has limit points they are either all in $A$ or some of them are not in $A$.  If they are all in $A$ then $A$ is closed.  But if the don't exist in $A$ then .... they exist in $B$ because $B$ is the entire universe.

Comment: OK, thanks.  Thing is, I'm trying to work from do Carmo's def. of "open": Given any point p in A, there is some ball centered on p that is a subset of A.  So my question would be: If we had a case where the boundary of A had points in common with the boundary of B, and p happened to be one of those common points, how would we even be able to define that ball?  What would take it's place?  Thanks.